# Turbo Trainer Cassette vs Bike Gears

Tags: gears, cassette, turbo-trainer

I’ve just purchased a Pinnacle Smart Trainer. In addition a 2nd hand Carerra bike.

In my incompetence with anything practical, I’ve not read the instructions. The turbo requires a 8/9/10/11 speed cassette. The bike has a 7 speed cassette (gears).

Will an 8 speed cassette work

Answer (score 3):

The name 8/9/10 speed freehub is in fact misleading. You can use 7 speed cassette on the trainer, but you'll need 4.5mm spacer for that (that you install on the freehub body before the cassette).

Answer (score 0):

Spacing of 8 speed and below is all the same, so your chain will be able to interface with an 8 speed cassette.

However, your shifters won't be able to cover all 8 gears, and you might have to adjust them slightly (via the barrel adjusters) every time you take the bike on and off the trainer. As long as you can live with those small issues, you can spin into the void to your heart's content.

Comment: I think the question it is more like about fitting the existing 7-speed drivetrain (including existing cassette) on the trainer which should be possible with spacers.

Comment: @DoNuT is correct. However, I think the proposition is that you could actually put an 8s cassette on the trainer, leave the bike as is, and just use the friction shifting and whatever gears you can access. I think this will work (but I'm not sure, no experience with older drivetrains).

Comment: @WeiwenNg Wouldn't an 8-speed cassette also require spacers on a hub that takes up to 11-speed, so presumably HG road that only takes current-gen cassettes without spacing? 1x1,85mm, If researched that correctly. So, it needs cassette and spacers (8-speed) vs. only spacers (7-speed with existing cassette).